# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined when " require('amadeus') "

Tags: referenceerror, amadeus

I have followed the Amadeus steps to set up the Amadeus account and installed the Node SDK using "npm install amadeus --save".

I wrote this function:

```
function fetchInfo(){
    let Amadeus = require('amadeus');
    let amadeus = new Amadeus({
        clientId: 'key',
        clientSecret: 'secret'
    });
}
```

in Javascript on WebStorm. Whenever I try to test this function on Chrome, it gives out "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". I also notice that there is no "color" on "require", looks like my WebStorm does not recognize this function. Am I missing any libraries?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `require` does not exist in the browser. You can try to use something like [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) or [requirejs](https://requirejs.org), but we don't recommend to do so, since you are exposing your credentials to the user. The SDK is designed to run on server-side only.

Comment: Hi Alnacle, thank you for your speedy response! Thank you for bring this up! So if I want to publish my website and want the users to be able to see what I extract (let's say flight price) using amadeus, is it possible? If yes, what extra steps do I need? Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you to start reading the [create a booking engine](https://developers.amadeus.com/get-started/create-a-flight-booking-engine-651) tutorial from the portal, to understand the APIs flow (Search -> Price -> Booking). Once that is clear, take a look to the prototypes apps released on GitHub in [Python](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-flight-booking-django) and [Node](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-flight-booking-node). You can use them as inspiration to get started coding your own app. Hope this helps!